# Tomee's OpenEJB implementation of Query not 100% compatible with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, openejb, apache-tomee

I have stumbled upon an issue with the implementation of `javax.persistence.Query`  from OpenEJB (which is JtaQuery) which I tend to think it is a bug but maybe I'm wrong.
I have this piece of code:

```
final Query fakeLoginQuery = this.systemSettingsEM
                .createNativeQuery("select value from SystemSettings where Name = 'IAM_FAKE_LOGIN'");
fakeLoginQuery.unwrap(SQLQuery.class).addScalar("value", StringType.INSTANCE);
final String fakeLogin = (String) fakeLoginQuery.getSingleResult();
```

now don't ask why I'm doing the thing in line 2 (it just seems that, although I'm specifying the dialect for my SQL Server, here - and just here from all the codebase - hibernate is using the simple dialect and not the one specified, but that's another problem)

**In Tomee** the implementation of `java.persistence.Query` from OpenEJB (JtaQuery) returns an instance from unwrap() which is different from the one it delegates to when doing `fakeLoginQuery.getSingleResult()`. Obviously, that instance it delegates to does not have the type mapping set and it yells with the dreadful:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

-9 being nvarchar.

**In JBoss** this thing work perfectly , meaning that the instance of `org.hibernate.SQLQuery` returned by `unwrap()` is the same as the instance to which `fakeLoginQuery.getSingleResult()` delegates to.

Any ideas why OpenEJB does this? Or is it the other way around and JBOss's implementation of `Query` does this only because "it knows" hibernate's ways?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following two ways:
Way 1. change StringType.INSTANCE to Hibernate.STRING as below:

`fakeLoginQuery.unwrap(SQLQuery.class).addScalar("value", Hibernate.STRING);`


Way 2. Create your own Hibernate dialect, for example, as below:

`public class YourDialect extends SQLServerDialect {
    public YourDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, Hibernate.STRING.getName());
    }
}`

:)